# Is it possible to get a consolidated view of iOS/Android analytics with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

We have an app that is available on iOS and Android.

How can we see a single metric in Firebase's analytics, of *all* "Active users" ? Having it separated via the Dashboard by iOS/Droid is great, but what about a consolidated view - that answers the simple question 'how many users does your app have' ?

Couldn't see that this was available anywhere via Firebase Analytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to consolidate them on the Dashboard. You can use BigQuery and create your own report.